# How to return multiple $http request that depend on each other in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two url endpoints say: "fruitInfo" and "fruitDetails"

I want to return an object that contains:

```
var fruitInfoDetails = {"fruitInfo": <contents of fruitInfo response data>,
"fruitDetails": <contents of fruitDetails response data>}
```

Inside a service I call:

```
var fruitInfoDetails = {};
this.getFruitInfo()
.then(function(data) {

   fruitInfoDetails['fruitInfo'] = data;
   this.getFruitDetails(data.nameOfFruit).then(function(data) {
        fruitInfoDetails['fruitDetails'] = data;      
   })
});
```

Assume the this.getFruitInfo() and this.getFruitDetauls() contains functions that return the $http promise going to each of those endpoints.

What is the proper/elegant way to do this? 
If there is a function that I could pass a list of fruits "[Apple, Pear, Orange]", and it could return me a list of fruitInfoDetails objects, that would be perfect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can make your own promise using the **$q** service, and resolve it when the 2nd call completes.

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('FruitService', function($http, $q) {
return {
    getFruitInfoDetails: function() {
        // make our own promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // 1st call
        $http.get("fruitInfo").then(function(fruitInfo) {
            // 2nd call
            $http.get("fruitDetails").then(function(fruitDetails) {

                deferred.resolve({
                    fruitInfo: fruitInfo,
                    fruitDetails:fruitDetails
                });
            });
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

You can also use **$q.all()** in order to wait for both requests to finish before resolving. It result in less indentation.

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('FruitService', function($http, $q) {
return {
    getFruitInfoDetails: function() {
        // make our own promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        // 1st call
        var infoPromise = $http.get("fruitInfo");
        var detailsPromise = $http.get("fruitDetails");

        $q.all([infoPromise, detailsPromise]).then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve({
                fruitInfo: data[0],
                fruitDetails: data[1]
            })
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

The requested retrieving a list of given fruits:

```
angular.module('mymodule').factory('FruitService', function($http, $q) {

return {
    getFruitInfoDetails: function(fruit) {
        // make our own promise
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // we'll asume that you can put the fruit as part of the path
        var infoPromise = $http.get("fruitInfo/" + fruit);
        var detailsPromise = $http.get("fruitDetails/" + fruit );

        $q.all([infoPromise, detailsPromise]).then(function(data) {
            deferred.resolve({
                fruitInfo: data[0],
                fruitDetails: data[1]
            })
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    getFruitList: function(fruits) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();

        // map our list of fruits to a list of the promises of fruit info
        var allPromises = fruits.map(function (fruit) {
            return this.getFruitInfoDetails(fruit);
        });

        // wait for all the fruits to be resolved then just resolve our own promise
        $q.all(allPromises).then(function(allTheFruitInfoDetails) {
            deferred.resolve(allTheFruitInfoDetails);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
};
});
```

Comment: Nice use of `$q.all`!

Comment: thank you, it does help make it easier to understand, and it allows for both requests to be done in parallel. :)

Comment: Could you show an example of a function in which someone were to pass a list of fruitNames in a list, and an array of "fruitInfoObjects" is to be returned?

Comment: @Rolando I edited the response to include that. Uhm, you might have to scope the getFruitInfoDetails call. but that's what you should be looking for. promise hell. :)

Comment: If promise hell is what I am looking for, you must be satan... your a master of them. Upvoted.

Comment: @Rolando Promises are a decent enough way of getting around the fact that javascript can't multithread. You'll have to get used to them if you're making large apps. :(

Comment: I fixed all the syntax mistakes as well. Now it should run. :D